# Get Album info in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, storagefolder

As from Windows Phone 8.1, it's possible to get access to the music files in the MusicLibrary.
I can read all files without problems.

But now I want to read Album info.

```
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> albums = 
     await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbum);

foreach (StorageFolder folder in albums)
{
    // how to get album info?            
}
```

How can I get album info (name, artist, album art) in that foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works ... sometimes:

```
var props = await myStorageFileOrFolder.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
```

For folders it seems to always be empty.

Comment: This seems correct! So I'll need to get the MusicProperties from the a file in the folder..

Comment: A little further clarification: There are no music properties for folders on WP (since you can't guarantee that a folder only has one album in it) and album art isn't available through GetThumbnailAsync at all. 

Everything else that the system has is exposed on the files in the library or SD card. Any case of missing data is because the system doesn't have it either.

Comment: @Adam I know StorageFolder doesn't have any music properties, but do you know if it is possible to get the album art from a StorageFile somehow?

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to get the album art from the StorageFile instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allSongList = 
  (await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();

foreach (var file in allSongList)
{
   var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
}
```