# How to get all album artists from KnownFolders.MusicLibrary storage folder?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

Hi I'm trying to get all the names of album artists as quickly and correctly as possible.

However, I realize that there is no API on Windows Runtime that can easily allow us to extract all the names like there was in WP8.

Since there can be subfolders within folders, I've made a recursive method that calls itself every time IStorageItem is not of Type StorageFile. Basically, I'm drilling into every folder until I reach an audio file and from there I can extract the file properties such as album artist. Afterwards, I call Distinct() on the List of album artists since there can multiples of the same artist from each audio file.

As you can probably tell, this seems to be very inefficient, it takes quite a while to get through all the recursive calls with a large number of music. I'm sure there is a way better way and I'm asking for help if anybody knows of a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar question seems [to be here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23429831/2681948).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The faster way available is to use `KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByArtist);` to get all of the music files on the device as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn639127.aspx) grouped into virtual folders for each artist. This is a device deep search so you won't have to do any recursive enumeration.

Once you have the list of folder you can run the same logic for finding the artist name from each folder in the results.