# Windows Phone 8.1 album art

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone 8 app which is basically a media player, I upgraded it to 8.1 Silverlight, However since the upgrade I am no longer able to view the album art for albums downloaded from xbox music since the upgrade.

```
AlbumCollection albumsTemp;
albumsTemp = lib.Albums;
foreach (var currentAlbum in albumsTemp)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("MusicGroup: LoadAlbums(): currentAlbum.HasArt = " + currentAlbum.HasArt);
}
```

This always returns false, whereas previously (on WP 8) it would be true and I could get the album art.

Does anyone know how to access the album art?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Music Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.musicproperties) class in order to access the Album details which also includes the `Album Art`:

Sample: [Get Album info in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429831/)

Reference: [StorageItemContentProperties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.storageitemcontentproperties.getmusicpropertiesasync)